# Socket.IO - setInverval every two minutes (Node JS)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I have an event in socket.io which broadcasts how many users are online (based on who is logged in) to the user.

What I think should be happening is that I ask the server to query the database **once** every two minutes using `setInterval`, and a rowset is returned, then emitted to the client.

What is happening though, is that *for each* user connected to the socket, it is calling the database on the server and pushing to the client.

I'm uncertain why this is doing this - I'd understand if I was asking it to do this from the client, but as it's the server emitting the event *to* the client, why would it be doing this several time for each user connected?

Thanks

```
io.on("connection", function(socket) {

  // Update online users' every two minutes
  setInterval(function() {

    var roomNum = 0;
    var outObj  = {};

    model.get_online_users(function(err, rowset) {

      // Loop thorugh the rowset, set the roomNum and built up out_obj to output
      io.to("room_number:"+roomNum).emit("online-users", outObj);

    }); // End `model callback`

  }, 120000); // End `get_online_users`

}); // End `io.on("connection")`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `io.on("connection", function(socket) { something(); });` is called for EVERY connected user, if you put a loop in this, the loop will loop paralelly for every connected user.

The `setInterval` should be outside of your `io.on("connection", function(socket) { });`, and it will run once, from your node server starting to the shutdown of the server.

**Example :**

```
setInterval(function() {

    var roomNum = 0;
    var outObj  = {};

    model.get_online_users(function(err, rowset) {
        io.to("room_number:"+roomNum).emit("online-users", outObj);
    });
}, 120000);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it! I added an example if needed.